# How to use pd.read_html for website table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

Hi I have the following table I was hoping to scrape:

https://www.footballdb.com/players/current.html?letter=B

[image]

I have tried to use the following code to scrape:

```
df= pd.DataFrame()
site= 'https://www.footballdb.com/players/current.html?letter=B'
df = pd.read_html(site)
```

However am getting the error:

> `ValueError: No tables found`

Does anyone have a solution to this error?

I can see that the `div class = "divtable divtable-striped"` but not sure how to extract.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: The table on your website is not a real one, it uses `div` instead of `table` so it won't work. See the doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html `This function searches for <table> elements and only for <tr> and <th> rows and <td> elements within each <tr> or <th> element in the table. <td> stands for “table data”.`

Answer (score 0):

There are no `table` elements on the page. So, pandas cannot find it. You need to select the table div.So,I would suggest you go for BeautifulSoup instead.